# Convert following MySQL query to Codeigniter equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm very new to CodeIgniter and I have some problem converting MySQL queries to CodeIgniter. I want to update a record in one table with condition on another relational table.

Following is my MySQL query

```
UPDATE `user` SET `securitytoken` = '71b9b5bc1094ee6eaeae8253e787d654'
WHERE `profileid` IN (SELECT pid FROM `profile` WHERE `email` = 'username@mail.com')
```

This works fine in phpMyAdmin, but I wanted the same to be converted to codeigniter update query. Can anyone help me to convert.

I'm using CI v3.0.3 in Local WAMP Server.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is code your query as is using

```
$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

and use the escape capabilities to take care of your one or two input values.

Pay attention to query bindings, may be useful in your case.

See: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

I would not try to use Active Records, your SQL is a bit too complex for that.

Comment: Audet, Thanks it worked for me but wanted to know about Active Records. :)

Comment: In the CodeIgniter V2 documentation, the query building class is known as Active Records, whereas in V3, it is referred to as the Query Builder Class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("UPDATE `user` SET `securitytoken` = '71b9b5bc1094ee6eaeae8253e787d654'
WHERE `profileid` IN (SELECT pid FROM `profile` WHERE `email` = 'username@mail.com')");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT pid FROM `profile` WHERE `email` = 'username@mail.com'")->row_array();

$this->db->set(`securitytoken`,'71b9b5bc1094ee6eaeae8253e787d654');
$this->db->where_in(`profileid`,$query['pid']);
$this->db->update('user');

//echo $this->db->last_query();
//exit;
```

Try this...!

Comment: I am not sure this will work.  According to the CodeIgniter documentation, the second argument for `where_in` needs to be a value or an array, http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data In your approach, you  would need to run the subquery first, get the value and then run the primary query, which is a pretty good approach since (though it looks clunky) it make use of the CI database class and is a bit easier to maintain.

Comment: I thought it will...  ok I understood. Thanks for the info.
@MarcAudet